# output should be without the 0 value

Tags: java

I am extracting number of coins (tens, fives, ones, quarter) from a certain amount of money. I have this code but the output should be : 10 pcs of 10 peso coin and 1 pcs of 1 peso coin (without the 0 pcs of 5 peso coin)

```
    double money = 121;
    int tens = 0;
    int fives = 0;
    int ones = 0;

    while (money !=0) {
        tens = (int) money / 10;
        money = money % 10;
        System.out.printlm(tens + "pcs of 10 peso coin");
        fives = (int) money / 5;
        money = money % 5;
        System.out.printlm(fives + "pcs of 5 peso coin");
        ones = (int) money % 1;
        money = money % 1;
        System.out.printlm(ones + "pcs of 1 peso coin");

    }
```

**output:**

```
12 pcs of 10 peso coin
0 pcs of 5 peso coin
1 pcs of 1 peso coin
```

**desired output:**

```
12 pcs of 10 peso coin
1 pcs of 1 peso coin.
```

Answer (score 3):

Add an `if` condition before each `println` statement.

For example :

```
...
if (tens > 0)
    System.out.println(tens + "pcs of 10 peso coin");
...
if (fives > 0)
    System.out.println(fives + "pcs of 5 peso coin");
...
if (ones > 0)
    System.out.println(ones + "pcs of 1 peso coin");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be more efficient. Removes the need to evaluate unnecessary values of money.

```
    If (money > 0) {
    tens = (int) money / 10;
    money = money % 10;
    System.out.printlm(tens + "pcs of 10 peso coin");
     }

    If (money > 0) {
    fives = (int) money / 5;
    money = money % 5;
    System.out.printlm(fives + "pcs of 5 peso coin");
    }

    If (money > 0) {
    ones = (int) money % 1;
    money = money % 1;
    System.out.printlm(ones + "pcs of 1 peso coin");
    }
```